# Calculating sum of List in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to scala. Currently I am trying to develop a calculator as scala project.
But while trying to find the sum I am getting problem. The following code doesn't compile.

```
def add [T](values :List[T]) : Option[T]={ 
  if (values.isInstanceOf[String]) {
    None
  }
  else if(values.isInstanceOf[Int] || values.isInstanceOf[Long] || values.isInstanceOf[Double]) {
    Some(values.sum)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to program Javascript in Scala? What exactly are you trying to do? `isInstanceOf` tests should never be required in a regular Scala program. There is almost always a better, more idiomatic way.

Comment: I am trying to define a generic method add which takes any number of input parameters of any type (Int,Double) and sum them up.Also I am from Java field that is why i used(isIntanceOf) it.I just started coding on scala.

Answer (score 1):

When you're new to a language, it is important to start slow and discover the abstractions rather than impose them right away without the experience to make it work. I also think it is a bad idea to just rely on standard library functions (unless you are in a hurry) like `sum` or to look at third-party libraries until you fully understand what the standard library offers.

So in other words, first let's look at ways to solve the problem just for `Int`:

```
def add(values: List[Int]) = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

The `reduce` function works because the type of the result matches the type of what is in the list. The contents are `Int`s, and the sum is an `Int`. You will also find this can be simplified with some syntactic sugar:

```
def add(values: List[Int]) = values.reduce(_ + _)
```

Wait until you see all the ways underscores get used in Scala.

As you keep studying, you will find that in order to accumulate a value that is a *different* type than what's in the list, you can use one of the `fold*` methods. But they can work here too, so for example you could also do this:

```
def add(values: List[Int]) = values.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

Now try to define the same function for `Long`, `Double`, or even `String`. You will find the implementations will be almost identical.

It's only when you see implementations that look *really* similar if not identical that you should even think about abstractions. One option to solve this problem is with [type classes](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html). They aren't easy for beginners though. Daniel Westheide wrote a great [post](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) on the topic, and frankly you would do well to read the whole [series](http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html) as you learn Scala.

I've really simplified things and glossed over a lot of topics (like why `foldLeft` has two parameter lists with the first one being 0 or what those crazy `implicit` things are in Daniel's type classes post), but my advice is to be patient and move slowly. Scala isn't easy, but you'll get it.

(But if you are in a hurry and you are a beginner, I think you are better off just using `sum` and then writing separate functions for each type. This would be an example of what agile author Kenny Rubin would call "necessary" or "unavoidable" technical debt, and that's to be expected from beginners. Just refactor later.)

Answer (score 0):

Or more generic (example with [amm](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL)):

```
@ import $ivy.`org.typelevel:cats_2.12:0.8.1` 
import $ivy.$                              
@ import cats._, cats.implicits._ 
import cats._, cats.implicits._
@ List(1, 2, 3).combineAll 
res2: Int = 6
@ List("1", "2", "3").combineAll 
res3: String = "123"
@ List(List(1, 2), List(), List(3)).combineAll 
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Or via [fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7BDBIxx/0). It works by using the [Monoid](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html) and [Traversable](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicativetraverse.html) typeclass.